# SignalR vs Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, signalr

I have a .Net based backend server which is hosted on Azure. I'm attempting to build an android app with Xamarin. The app will have a chat feature that will allow the users to communicate with each other. 
I have been using SignalR for simple real time web tasks and I know much of the same can be achieved with Google Cloud Messaging for android however I have read that SignalR is more reliable than Google Cloud. I'm more in favor of using Google cloud messaging service as it doesn't require constant connection to the back end hence saves battery time. But the only dilemma I have is that whether I would be able to implement the chat for the web. 
The idea is to use SignalR for web and Google Cloud Messaging for the android. I will need to make sure that both chat sync. Is it possible to do so? or should I use SignalR for both?
Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use signalR on both platform. I am also using signalR on my application. Even its giving me better service instead of only Google cloud messaging. My one of android application included signalR and GCM both. when my application is foreground i use signalR and when it go to background i use GCM. and still it stable for me. You can try like this

Comment: appreciate ur answer! Yes it makes more sense to use signalR but there are somethings that can't be achieved or would be hard to achieve with signalR than they would be with GCM

Comment: I am agree with you, but still GCM is not so reliable. It does miss to send notification 1 on every 10 (from my experience)

Comment: hello  @Masum is it possible to generate notification using signalr alone even when app is in background mode

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran I didn't use signalR for background. I used only to foreground but I believe if you use signalR using service then you can figure it out. Remember signalR connection could be lost after certain time so you have to check when it gets lost the connection then you must make connection again. Obviously signalR library provide you an event where you can detect your connection get lost.

Comment: how is the battery consumption of singal r? is it constantly keeping connection open and draining battery of the user?

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud messaging (GCM) is not recommended for making chat applications. You should stick with SignalR. Google cloud messaging is usually used for push notifications.

If you really want to use GCM then I will recommend you FCM, but it is a separate solution in contrast to SignalR (& .net)

> **[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)** (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See
>   the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

**Update**

GCM (or FCM) will have advantage over signalR considering battery usage.

Comment: I didn't use FCM. but i want to know, Is FCM work while application is been closed like gcm?

Comment: Yes FCM is a super set of GCM, and run on the same infrastructure. Anything you can do with GCM you can do with FCM.

Comment: Thanks it mekes sense.